# blank page on M2 on ubuntu on aws after 'successful' install

Tags: magento2

I've successfully installed a t2.small instance on AWS with Ubuntu 14.04. I installed apache 2.4.7 and php 5.6.18 and mysql 5.6.x. Prior to installing M2-ce I could access docroot no problem from any browser getting the basic "Index of" message from apache.

I installed M2.02 from the command line with sample data and it reported a successful installation of all components and sample data

> Post installation file permissions check...
>   For security, remove write permissions from these directories: '/var/www/html/magento2-ce/app/etc'
>   [Progress: 363 / 363]
>   [SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.

Now when attempting to access magento2-ce docroot, I get a completely blank page. Same thing for /admin_XXXX.

Chrome reports the dreaded server side 500 error. I've set all permissions per the installation guide. I'm posting this here because the problem arose AFTER installing M2. I'd appreciate any info on where to look to solve this. I've dug through the apache2 access log and error log and they indicate no problems with apache.

I have updated apache.conf to modify docroot to /var/www/html/magento2-ce.

My magento2-ce directory and all of its descendants are owned by magento:www-data.

phpmyadmin runs perfectly from the docroot.

Chrome reports the server is barfing on favicon.ico but says nothing more (e.g. no 404 etc.)

Comment: Try enabling [developer mode](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html#config-mode); it'll show errors in the browser. You might also have some luck using a browser inspector (unless it's truly loading nothing). Finally, make sure [Apache rewrites](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite) are enabled.

Comment: system is in developer mode, rewrites are set to 1. And, yes the page is truly loading nothing. Stuck with the 500 error on load. I'm running out of ideas here.

Comment: One, when you say rewrites set to 1, you're referring to the CLI option `--use-rewrites=1`? Did you also make sure [Apache is set for rewrites](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-rewrites2.4) and restart Apache? Two, you said you modified `apache.conf` but on Apache 2.4, you want to modify `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`, I think. Three, you can set a value for `error_log` in `php.ini` to see if that shows anything. Finally, make sure you can render a simple file like `hello.html` from the Magento docroot.